# _destroy attribute not destroying record

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have simplified my update form for demo purposes:

```
class DesignerLayout < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :designer_panels, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :designer_panels
```

_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @designer_layout do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :designer_panels, @designer_layout.designer_panels do |designer_panel_builder| %>
    <%= designer_panel_builder.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to '#', class: 'remove-item' do %>
      <%= content_tag :span %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

form.js

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.remove-item').click(function(){
    $(this).prev('input[type="hidden"]').val("1");
  })
})
```

The following is sent to server:

```
Processing by DesignerLayoutsController#update as HTML
   Parameters: { ... "designer_layout"=>{"designer_panels_attributes"=>{"0"=>{"_destroy"=>"1", "id"=>"5"}}} ...
```

As you can see, the _destroy attribute with a value of "1" is sent with the id of the specific panel. However, the panel belonging to the layout is not deleted. Why?

Comment: can you show your strong param to whitelist the params ?

Comment: def designer_layout_params
    params[:designer_layout].permit!
  end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `allow_destroy: true` in model:

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :designer_panels, allow_destroy: true
```

And, make sure to whitelist the `_destroy` using strong param:

```
params.require(:designer_layout).permit(designer_panels_attributes: [:id, :_destroy])
```